# PostgreSQL analogy for Oracle's dbms_alert package

Tags: postgresql

Is there in PostgreSQL DB any mechanism to do same or similar change notifications like Oracle's dbms_alert package do?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! can't figure how i miss this in docu...